# Microsoft bot Installation

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

I'm curious to understand why my bot is not getting automatically installed on the personal scope after initially installing it in a team scope. Meanwhile, when I install other applications from the store within a team, the personal bot is automatically installed, and a welcome card is sent.

Could this be related to my manifest file? Am I misunderstanding something? Is it necessary for users to install the app in both the Team scope and a personal scope to enable the ability to send cards to users?

Please advise.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The default install scope determines the installation target when a user adds the app. By setting the default install scope to "personal", the app will be installed in the personal scope by default.

To configure the default install scope in your app manifest, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your app manifest file.
2. Add the defaultInstallScope property.
3. Set the value of the defaultInstallScope property to "personal".

   ```
   "defaultInstallScope": "personal"
   ```

*Note: The default install scope can only be set to one scope at a time.*

For more info please refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's exactly what I did, but when I tried sending a card just after adding the app to the team, I've got "(ConversationBlockedByUser) User blocked the conversation with the bot."

Comment: Is there any policy assigned to user in admin centre which blocks the user to interact with bot? Could you please check?

Comment: Also, could you please right click on your app and try to unblock the app as shown in below screenshot? https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxCXk.png